# NFC application development on android

Tags: android, nfc

I was wondering that can I develop applications on any android-based smartphone that is nfc-enabled or are there limitations on the kernel not to use some part of nfc functionalities ? And can you give smartphone examples that I can develop applications on nfc with no limitations. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />` , which tells Android Market that your application uses the NFC API. The declaration should include an `android:required` attribute that indicates whether you want Android Market to filter the application from devices that do not offer NFC support.